# Typedefs included, but not functions

Tags: c, function, matlab, include, codeblocks

I'm writing some code that uses a C library provided by MATLAB (to extract data from *.mat files). In my IDE (Code::Blocks), I've included the folder containing the necessary "mat.h", which is on a network drive. My code recognises types defined in mat.h when I do this, but whenever I call functions from the file I get an "undefined reference" error. This is the same case for the example code MathWorks provides. What sort of problem usually causes this?

```
#include "mat.h"
int main (void) {
   MATFile *pmat; // Compiles only when compiler is told to search in mat.h directory
   pmat = matOpen("example_filename", "r"); // Never compiles
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks!
Cameron

Answer (score 2):

"undefined reference" is normally a linker error. It's not a problem of a header file. You need to tell the linker to link MATLAB's library (or a dedicated object) to your program.

No idea how this is done in Code::Blocks though. In the Code:Blocks documentation it is described [here](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-340001.11.13).

Comment: Thanks yes it was a linker issue!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the contents of mat.h? Does it declare `matOpen()`? Also, does the error occur when compiling or linking? If it's during the link phase, you probably need to reference the library that contains the implementation of `matOpen()` (a .lib in Windows, or .a in Unix). The .h file only declares the function.

Comment: Thanks yes it was a linker issue!